# react router changes url but not navigating to page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having trouble in changing the page in react with react-router-dom. here is my router :-

```
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from '../pages/grocery';
import Profile from '../pages/profile';
import CheckoutPage from '../pages/checkout';
export default function Routes(props) {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" name="Home" component={HomePage} exact />
          <Route path="/profile" name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/checkout" name="Checkout" component={CheckoutPage} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}
```

and here is my Link tag

```
<Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that the second Route element, have a "/" too, and the first one will access any element that starts with an "/".
How to fix this?
with Route you can put "exact" just before path, so it will only access that specific route, no matters what comes after that.
example:

```
<Route exact path="/" name="Home" component={HomePage} />
<Route exact path="/profile" name="Profile" component={Profile} />
<Route exact path="/checkout" name="Checkout" component={CheckoutPage} />
```

this way you will not have problems accessing your others pages or components.

Comment: This is a good point, although you should also mention that if the order of the components were reversed without using `exact`, that would also work as it matches the first route in the `Switch`, because adding `exact` can cause a path which matches none of the components to render nothing - whereas leaving it as normal will allow any unknown routes to render the `Home` component

Comment: Exactly, the order also matters, as if you put the HomePage route at the end, it will also work as is the last item to be checked